# Import Error: No module named http django

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have an error occurring in my wsgi.py file. It's complaining that:

```
File "(directory)/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5 py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django import http
ImportError: cannot import name http
```

I checked that the directory http exists in (directory)/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5 py2.7.egg/django/. Also, when importing django.core, there is no problem, but when importing any of the other modules, it gives the same error. Here is the directory information for (directory)/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5 py2.7.egg/django/:

```
django:
    bin  conf  contrib  core  db  dispatch  forms  http  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  middleware  shortcuts  template  templatetags  test  utils  views
```

And here's the directory info for http:

```
http:
    cookie.py  cookie.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  multipartparser.py  multipartparser.pyc  request.py  request.pyc  response.py  response.pyc  utils.py  utils.pyc
```

EDIT:

error given in python shell:

```
>>from django import http
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name http

>>from django import core
>>
```

Error was solved by deleting a local directory also called django. However, the local directory was in place because I am putting my site on a shared server that I cannot edit the site-packages of. Is there a way for the application to read both from my local and the server's django folders so that I can use modules that are not on the server's django directory?

Comment: Do you have a local directory also called django?

Comment: Open a command prompt / terminal type > Python > then try doing the import

Comment: I might have another local directory called django. How would I go about checking for this? Typing the command prompt for the import gives the same error but typing from django import core gives no error. Specifically error given is in edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn your local django folder into a namespace. This tells the python interpreter to continue traversing the path for modules, even if it finds a matching module earlier (i.e. the 'django' module you added).

Add this to the __init__.py in your local django folder:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
```

When python finds this module, it runs this code to register it as a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable to point to your local modules.